# Is the Auction House a global AH in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the Diablo III Auction House, is it a global AH, or does it only display items from a certain sector that they place you in?

And, is it the same for both real money and gold, or is one global and one is not?

I'd imagine having one large global AH would destroy the market, but if it's sectored, is it a large enough sector?

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Diablo 3 Auction Houses (both Real Money and gold) are regional, one of the same three regions there are for servers:

The Americas, Asia, and Europe.

Additionally, Hardcore characters are entirely separate from "softcore" characters - this means no trading and a separate shared stash, but it also means a separate pair of auction houses to boot.

Answer (score 5):

The gold and real money auction houses were closed on March 18, 2014, [source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9972208129).

> Q. When will the gold and real-money auction houses be removed from
> the game?
>
> The gold and real-money auction houses will be shut down on
> Tuesday, March 18, 2014.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question posed.

Comment: You're right. However, they have been closed and the question is really no longer useful. But we are not closing questions that are no longer relevant.

Comment: I'd recommend suggesting an edit to an existing answer, or at least answering the question.

Comment: @Frank: I disagree, I think this does answer the question.  The answer to *"How do I trade items in D3"* is *"You can't anymore,"* which is a legitimate answer.  The answer to *"Are the auction houses global?"* is *"No, because they don't exist anymore."*  +1 for keeping old answers up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

There is a different action house per region (if you're using in-game gold) *and* per currency (if you're using real-life money). Hardcore players, additionally, have their *separate* in-game-gold-only per-region action houses and are locked out from the rest.

You can see the full list and availability of each action house [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status). More information is [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/services/auction-house/how-to).

Answer (score 1):

Each region has multiple auction houses: one for gold and one for each real-life currency supported in the region. Items can only be listed in a single auction house at a time.

That means that the gold auction house is region-restricted.